# Output multiple left joints in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so I have a table that has 2 fields referencing the `sponsorID` from another table. I need to pull out the `nickname` from other table from both fields.

```
accounts table
sponsorID Nickname
   1        Rob
   2        Mark

tables table
ID sponsorID1 sponsorID2
1       1        2
```

I need to pull out the nickname using `sponsorID1` and `sponsorID2`. What have I done so far is

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=helpinghands', 'root', '');
$table = $conn->query("SELECT a.l1_1 as lv1_1, a2.l2_1 as lv2_1 FROM tables LEFT JOIN accounts AS a ON tables.l1_1=a.sponsorID LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON tables.l2_1=a2.sponsorID");
for ($t in $table) {
echo $nickname1 = $t['??'];
echo $nickname2 = $t['??'];
}
```

I don't know how to do the right query. It just shows me a blank page. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just run it directly on the SQL server first until you determine the query, THEN move it to PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working as follows:

```
SELECT t.ID, a1.nickname, a2.nickname
FROM tables AS t
    LEFT JOIN accounts AS a1 ON t.sponsorID1 = a1.sponsorID
    LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON t.sponsorID2 = a2.sponsorID;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working, I just changed the line

```
$table = $conn->query("SELECT a.l1_1 as lv1_1, a2.l2_1 as lv2_1 FROM tables LEFT JOIN accounts AS a ON tables.l1_1=a.sponsorID LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON tables.l2_1=a2.sponsorID");
```

To

```
$table = $conn->query("SELECT a.nickname as lv1_1, a2.nickname as lv2_1 FROM tables LEFT JOIN accounts AS a ON tables.l1_1=a.sponsorID LEFT JOIN accounts AS a2 ON tables.l2_1=a2.sponsorID");
```

I forgot to put the `nickname` field to the query.